# Compiling GUI Java Client, Penguin Icon instead of Window

Tags: java, icons, compiling

I am trying to run a java client program on Ubuntu through command line. This program connects to a server program written in C. My java program has GUI and many classes, so when I compile it, I get a bunch of `MyClass$.class` files. I type

```
java MyClass
```

to run and instead of getting the window I am expecting from the program, a penguin icon appears on the bar on the left hand side of screen [like so](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BzcTs.jpg). When I left click the icon, it offers the name of my program (Client Chat) and Quit. When I click Client Chat, nothing that I can see or am aware of happens. Have I done something wrong in compiling or running this program? How can I get my GUI screen to appear on the screen?

Comment: P.S. That's not a penguin

Comment: It's not? what is it then?

Comment: It's the Java logo: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_(software_platform)#Mascot

Answer (score 0):

I made a really dumb mistake. The GUI wasn't set to visible >_<